# Manipulate json data in angular from .net core web api

Tags: c#, .net, json, angular, asp.net-web-api

I have a repository that returns `IQueryable< Player >`. In that repository I return `context.Player;`

A service calls that repository and returns also `IQueryable< player >`.

A controller calls that service and returns `IActionResult.. OK(Service.Get())`

If I call that controller from Postman I get the json with all the players.

But now I call that controller from angular and for every player I see `[object Object]`.

This is my controller from .net

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public IActionResult Get()
{
  var players = PlayerService.GetAll();
  return Ok(players);
}
```

This is my service

```
public IQueryable<Player> GetAll()
{
  return PlayerRepository.GetAll();
}
```

This is my repository

```
 public IQueryable<Player> GetAll()
 {
   return context.Players;
 }
```

This is my component from angular

```
public players: IPlayers[];
constructor(http: Http, @Inject('ORIGIN_URL') originUrl: string) {
  http.get(originUrl + '/api/Players/Get').subscribe(result => {
    this.players = result.json();
  });
```

And this is what i show in html :  `{{players}}`

Can someone help me with how I can access the values from that json?

Comment: try {{players | json}} or {{players[0].name}}

Comment: Same thing.      I put the code for all the methods for a better view.

Comment: add console.log(this.players) after line this.players = result.json() and look at chrome console window

Comment: for players[0].Name now doesn't show anything. For console i have 121 objects ( for my 121 players). If i expand one, i can chose between my 121 objects. I expand again and i have 0 : Object Name : Ronaldo league : La liga     1: Object Name : Messi league : La liga and so on

Comment: Here is the picture   https://s3.postimg.org/jbyv3ixs3/Untitled.jpg

Comment: players[0].Name => players[0].name

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the problem. In my database the value was player.Name so i tried the same.